# Processing thousands of files in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing, celery, airflow, etl

I have thousands of files stored in MongoDB which I need to fetch and process.
Processing consists of a few steps which should be done sequentially. The whole process takes around ~2 mins per file from start to end.

My question is how to do that as fast as possible while being scalable in future? Should I do it in pure python or should I maybe use Airflow + Celery (or even Celery by itself)? Are there any other ways/suggestions I could give a try?

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The main bottleneck will quite likely be the reading of the data into memory. You can of course try to reduce your CPU load as well, but it's not going to make the I/O any faster in wall clock time.

Answer (score 2):

Celery alone is precisely made to do what you need - no need to reinvent the wheel.